# Forcing systemd to mount a filesystem as remote

Tags: mount, systemd

I have a remote filesystem on Storage Area Network accessed by Fibre Channel cards. These cards need firmware to work under Debian.
I want this filesystem to be mounted by systemd *after* firmware loading is finished.

But systemd is stupid enough to treat my remote filesystem as local and tries to mount it as a `local-fs.target` early during boot when the FC cards are not operatable yet!

I tried adding `x-systemd.requires=network-online.target` in /etc/fstab, but it just creates a dependency loop (i.e. to start network the local filesystem need to be mounted, and to mount my remote (treated by systemd as local) filesystem network needs to be running).

I checked https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html

Any ideas how to tackle it?

Comment: Edit: I think I found a way: make a `/lib/systemd/system/mnt-scratch.mount` file and under [Unit] add a line `After=multipathd.service`